# Append String without repeating CASE expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I append a string to a field based on a condition without having to repeat the same case statement multiple times in the SELECT?

For example.

```
CASE WHEN t1.location = A THEN '1111' ELSE '2222' + t1.telephone1,
CASE WHEN t1.location = A THEN '1111' ELSE '2222' + t1.telephone2
```

If I had to select 10 columns this way I would have to copy paste 10 times. I was thinking of a possible variable or CTE but that seems like I would have to repeat the case anyway?

Comment: You still have SOME rework, but you can do a CROSS APPLY to get your string you want, then just apply that string to every phone number.

Comment: Agreed `CROSS APPLY (VALUES (...` is your ticket

Comment: You could also put the logic in an inline function. It's more reusable and won't be a problem for performance provided the number of rows is relatively small.

Comment: @sTTu - are you talking about an inline table valued function or a scalar UDF? I would say definitely don't do a scalar UDF, but a TVF would certainly be reusable (although would this logic actually be reused?).

Comment: @AnthonyHancock, tbh either; a TVF could be utilized as a cross apply, however a scalar function would be fine, depending on use-case - hence my comment about small number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with a CTE:

```
with t1_as_cte (myexpression,telephone1,telephone2)
 as (
    select CASE WHEN t1.location = A THEN '1111' ELSE '2222' end myexpression,
           t1.telephone1,
           t1.telephone2
           from mytable t1
    )
  select myexpression + telephone1, myexpression + telephone2
  from t1_as_cte
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So if you have 10 phone number columns (for some reason) that you want to prefix all of them based on location, then use CROSS APPLY VALUES.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test;

CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    TestID TINYINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Location] VARCHAR(1)
    ,Phone1 VARCHAR(15)
    ,Phone2 VARCHAR(15)
    ,Phone3 VARCHAR(15)
    ,Phone4 VARCHAR(15)
    ,Phone5 VARCHAR(15)
    ,Phone6 VARCHAR(15)
    ,Phone7 VARCHAR(15)
    ,Phone8 VARCHAR(15)
    ,Phone9 VARCHAR(15)
    ,Phone10 VARCHAR(15)
)
;

INSERT INTO #Test
([Location],Phone1,Phone2,Phone3,Phone4,Phone5,Phone6,Phone7,Phone8,Phone9,Phone10)
VALUES
('A','PhoneA','PhoneA','PhoneA','PhoneA','PhoneA','PhoneA','PhoneA','PhoneA','PhoneA','PhoneA')
,('B','PhoneB','PhoneB','PhoneB','PhoneB','PhoneB','PhoneB','PhoneB','PhoneB','PhoneB','PhoneB')
;

SELECT
    TST.TestID
    ,Phone1 = CONCAT(PFX.Prefix,TST.Phone1)
    ,Phone2 = CONCAT(PFX.Prefix,TST.Phone2)
    ,Phone3 = CONCAT(PFX.Prefix,TST.Phone3)
    ,Phone4 = CONCAT(PFX.Prefix,TST.Phone4)
    ,Phone5 = CONCAT(PFX.Prefix,TST.Phone5)
    ,Phone6 = CONCAT(PFX.Prefix,TST.Phone6)
    ,Phone7 = CONCAT(PFX.Prefix,TST.Phone7)
    ,Phone8 = CONCAT(PFX.Prefix,TST.Phone8)
    ,Phone9 = CONCAT(PFX.Prefix,TST.Phone9)
    ,Phone10 = CONCAT(PFX.Prefix,TST.Phone10)
FROM #Test AS TST
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES(CASE WHEN TST.[Location] = 'A' THEN '1111' ELSE '2222' END)
) AS PFX (Prefix)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I wasn't aware that cross apply could be used with values like this. It certainly helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function. Or you can use Cross Apply and Outer Apply